# Adding MPU6500 Gyroscope, Accelerometer Module to RK3566 Single Board Computer Android11 Platform

Tags: linux

I'm trying to connect the MPU6500 gyroscope and accelerometer module via the i2c bus to a single-board computer on the Android 11 system and I'm looking at a similar example in which the module is added to the device tree and the PINCTRL of the interrupt output is added:

```
&pinctrl {
    mpu6500_irq_gpio: mpu6500-irq-gpio {
        rockchip,pins = 
            <2 RK_PA6 RK_FUNC_GPIO &pcfg_pull_up>;
    };
};
&i2c6 {
    status = "okay";
    
    mpu6500@69 {
        compatible = "mpu6500_acc";
        reg = <0x69>;
        type = <SENSOR_TYPE_ACCEL>;
        irq-gpio = <&gpio2 RK_PA6 IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_FALLING>;
        irq_enable = <1>;
        poll_delay_ms = <30>;
        layout = <0>;
        status = "okay";
    };
    mpu6500_gyro@69 {
        compatible = "mpu6500_gyro";
        reg = <0x69>;
        type = <SENSOR_TYPE_GYROSCOPE>;
        irq_enable = <0>;
        poll_delay_ms = <30>;
        status = "okay";
    };
};
```

Tell me what this PINCTRL property means and whether it must be added to the device tree or not?

```
&pinctrl {
    mpu6500_irq_gpio: mpu6500-irq-gpio {
        rockchip,pins = 
            <2 RK_PA6 RK_FUNC_GPIO &pcfg_pull_up>;
    };
};
```